# Insert SOAP web service payload into JMS using Mule

Tags: soap, jms, mule

I have the following Mule flow. What I'm trying to achieve is simply to put the SOAP message into the JMS queue.

The content of the message in the JMS queue is

```
org.mule.module.xml.stax.ReversibleXMLStreamReader@3c7e9afa
```

What am I missing in the transformer?

```
<object-to-string-transformer name="Object_to_String" doc:name="Object to String"/>

<flow name="soapServiceFlow">

    <http:listener config-ref="SOAP_JMS_HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/soap" doc:name="HTTP"/>

    <cxf:proxy-service 
    configuration-ref="CXF_Configuration" 
    doc:name="CXF" 
    payload="envelope" 
    wsdlLocation="service.wsdl"
    namespace="http://www.examples.com/wsdl/ReportService" 
    port="ReportPort" 
    service="ReportService" />
    <logger message="#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <jms:outbound-endpoint queue="my.requests" connector-ref="Active_MQ" doc:name="JMS" transformer-refs="Object_to_String">
        <jms:transaction action="NONE"/>
    </jms:outbound-endpoint>
</flow>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a transformation error and you can simply use `object-to-string-transformer` to make it work:-

```
 <object-to-string-transformer doc:name="Object to String"/>
```

before your JMS outbound

Comment: The exception is gone. But now my JMS message details are: org.mule.module.xml.stax.ReversibleXMLStreamReader@3c7e9afa Is it possible to have the actual soap message in there?

Comment: I've edited the question to show the new flow as per your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Before the logger, add `<object-to-string-transformer doc:name="Object to String"/>` for you to see the string content of the class `org.mule.module.xml.stax.ReversibleXMLStreamReader@3c7e9afa`